# WorddPress website admin part not working correctly - I think ajax/json issue

Tags: ajax, wp-admin, json

The admin part of my wordpress website  is not functioning like expected.

Almost every time I click a save button or similar I get an empty page with no source returned (shows up as blank in my webbrowser)

I suspect this is an AJAX issue where maybe my webhost is blocking HTTP Ajax requests.

I first suspected mod_security - but disabling that in cpanel made no difference.

Example:
If I on https://example.com/wp-admin/options-discussion.php click "Save changes" button I get an empty page returned

Any ideas on possible reasons? I have cpanel on my (new) webhost.

Comment: How long ago did you switch hosts? If it was within the past 72 hours, your nameservers may not have fully propagated yet, meaning you may just have to wait until everything switches fully to the new host. If it has been at least that long, usually your host is a better place to start asking support questions as it's likely specific to your migration.

Comment: Have you disabled all your plugins and switched to a default theme (Twenty [something])? That should help you narrow down the issue.

Comment: empty page doesn't really sound like an AJAX issue but rather that your host is overwhelmed with the request, did you contact them yet?

Comment: @kero all other domains on my website functions including a forum - but I will try contact them later today